# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Platform') for Here Maps with React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, here-api, heremaps

I'm using the demo code to build a simple Here map using React + Typescript. I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Platform')` at line #11:

```
   8 | React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
   9 |     if(!mapRef.current) return;
  10 | 
> 11 |     const platform = new H.service.Platform({
  12 | ^       apikey: // my API key
  13 |     });
  14 |
```

And here is the beginning of the typescript file below:

```
import React from "react";
import * as H from "here-maps";

export function DisplayMap() {

    const mapRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(!mapRef.current) return;

        const platform = new H.service.Platform({
            apikey: // my API key
        });

        const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        ...
```

Any clue what is the problem? I inspected `H.service` and it is a namespace and `Platform` is defined inside it. Not sure why it is undefined!

And this is my package.json file:

```
...
"dependencies": {
        
        "@types/heremaps": "^3.1.5",
        "ajv": "^6.12.0",
        "here-maps": "^3.0.2",
        "react": "^16.13.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.6",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

we can integrate a map into our React component. That said, we’ll need to make some mild adjustments to the instructions to adapt to the way React works, so let’s go step-by-step.

Loading the API Code Libraries
Like mentioned in the quick starting guide, we need to load the core and service modules. These script tags are still added to the head of the document, same as the guide there, but we’ll put them in the /public/index.html file. We can also add the meta-tag to optimize the performance for mobile at the same time:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <title>React App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
  ></script>
</head>
```

Creating the reusable Map component
Now that we have loaded the HERE Map Libraries, lets create a reusable Map component by creating a file src/DisplayMapClass.js and add the following code:

```js
// src/DisplayMapClass.js
import * as React from 'react';

export class DisplayMapClass extends React.Component {
  mapRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    // The map instance to use during cleanup
    map: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    const H = window.H;
    const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: "{HERE-API-KEY}"
    });

    const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Create an instance of the map
    const map = new H.Map(
      this.mapRef.current,
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
      {
        // This map is centered over Europe
        center: { lat: 50, lng: 5 },
        zoom: 4,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      }
    );
 
    this.setState({ map });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Cleanup after the map to avoid memory leaks when this component exits the page
    this.state.map.dispose();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Set a height on the map so it will display
      <div ref={this.mapRef} style={{ height: "500px" }} />
    );
  }
}
```

Now, lets import the DisplayMapClass.js component in the App.js to render the map.

```js
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import {DisplayMapClass} from './DisplayMapClass';

function App() {
return (
<DisplayMapClass />
);
}
export default App;
```

Adding Interactivity
While the previous map may suffice with your business needs, many apps require interactivity. Luckily, the JS SDK gives us ways to add this functionality trivially.

We’ll first start by adding two new imports to our public/index.html file to import the files from the HERE SDK required for it’s related features to function:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <title>React App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"
  ></script>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"
  ></script>
</head>
```

Then, we can use the new functionality enabled by those imports by making some minor changes to the component we’ve already built.

```js
export default class DisplayMapClass extends React.Component {
  mapRef = React.createRef();
  state = {
    map: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const H = window.H;
    const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: "{HERE-API-KEY}"
    });

    const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    const map = new H.Map(
      this.mapRef.current,
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
      {
        center: { lat: 50, lng: 5 },
        zoom: 4,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      }
    );

    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    // This variable is unused and is present for explanatory purposes
    const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components to allow the user to interact with them
    // This variable is unused
    const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

    this.setState({ map });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.map.dispose();
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.mapRef} style={{ height: "500px" }} />;
  }
}
```

Now we should be able to zoom in and out of maps, pan to locations of our choosing, and even have a convenient API present for our users to utilize

For more details please check the below tutorials. which explain how we can integrate react with the here maps.
https://developer.here.com/tutorials/react/